# HyperLink Script ArcGIS 10.3

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, hyperlink

I am trying to write a script (python) to open an external exe file on the server once I click on a feature in ArcGIS. The script must have 2 parameters in namely `FacilityId` and `UserID`. The exe file will take the parameters and write it to an SQL table where another function triggers from.

This is the python script I have thus far... (Please forgive, me I have not clue what I am doing):

```
import webbrowser
def OpenLink ( [FacilityId] ):
  path = "W://QGIS//PREMISQGIS.exe" 
  webbrowser.open(path)
  return
```

The above script at least opens the exe and asks if I want to run it - as soon as I do, it says it doesn't have parameters?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the webbrowser module to run an executable (I think?  Or at least you shouldn't if you can).  That is meant to open web pages.  Instead, Have a look at the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module.  I think you can call this executable with the Facility ID and User Id like this:

```
import subprocess

def openLink(facilityId, userId):
    path = r"W:\QGIS\PREMISQGIS.exe"
    cmd = '%s %s %s' %(path, facilityId, userId)
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    return proc

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # add your parameters here:
    facilityId = 'facility1'
    userId = 'your_name'
    openLink(facilityId, userId)
```

Please note that you can accomplish the same thing with a simple batch file.